# Set page load Processing time

Tags: javascript, jsp

I add loading image in code that image loading till when the whole process is not completely done but how i know the page loading time because the processing time always change according to the data.

I have mention the time in my below  javascript code.

```
<script>
$('#save').click(function() {
   $('#loading').html('<img src="./images/ima.png"> loading...');
   $.ajax({
      success : function(d) {
         setTimeout(function() {
            $('#loading').html('<img src="./images/images.png">');
         }, 2000);
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `complete` to hide your loading image, instead of `setout` in ajax success method, this way loading image will be hidden once ajax request completes,irrespective of error or success.

```
<script>
      $('#save').click(function() {
       $('#loading').html('<img src="./images/ima.png"> loading...');
       $.ajax({
          success : function(d) {
             //handle success
          },
          error: function(xhr) { 
            // hanndle if error occurs 
           },

          complete: function() {
              //hide loading here
               $('#loading').html('<img src="./images/images.png">');
          }
       });
    });
 </script>
```